# how to use group by function for this code

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is this code true syntactically? But it does not work in my sql developer

```
SELECT
    locations.country_id,
    locations.street_address,
    departments.department_name
FROM
    departments
    JOIN locations ON departments.location_id = locations.location_id
    JOIN countries ON locations.country_id = countries.country_id
    JOIN employees ON departments.manager_id = employees.manager_id
GROUP BY
    locations.country_id;
```

Comment: by countries.country_id

Comment: Just use `JOIN` instead of using in `WHERE`

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what you're trying to do? You can add a GROUP BY clause at the end simply by adding `GROUP BY locations.country_id,locations.street_address,departments.department_name`, but I have a feeling that's not what you really want to achieve?

Comment: Please add sample data of both input and output

Comment: Tip of today: Use table aliases to save some typing. (Also makes the query easier to read.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you asked but this may be a solution

```
SELECT locations.country_id,locations.street_address,departments.department_name 
FROM
departments,
locations,
countries,
employees
WHERE
employees.department_id = departments.department_id
AND locations.country_id    = countries.country_id
AND departments.location_id = locations.location_id
AND departments.manager_id=employees.manager_id;
GROUP BY locations.country_id, departments.department_name
```

Comment: If you don't add sample data and desired output will be hard to understand what you want

Comment: dear this is sql developer's default tables.

Comment: We don't have the output you need, please add the output, so we don't know, even if we have the data, where you wanna go

Answer (score 0):

use explicit join, comma separated table will create cross join so change your join like below

```
      SELECT locations.country_id,
      locations.street_address,departments.department_name
     FROM
     departments join
     locations on departments.location_id = locations.location_id
     join countries on locations.country_id    = countries.country_id
     join employees on departments.manager_id=employees.manager_id
```

As you have not use any aggregate function so you have not need group by

Comment: here I can not group, by country.

Comment: @KanbarzadehNurlan you didnt use any aggregate function so why you need group by ?

Comment: @KanbarzadehNurlan share your tables data and expected output that would be easy to guide properly

Comment: this is oracle default tables.